# Jest Mocking useSelector is shown as untested in coverage report

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I was testing useSelector using the following code below. Although **when I looked at my coverage report I saw in red that it wasn't actually being tested**... Is there a way to test those lines?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render  } from '../../../test-utlities/test-utlities';

import IndividualInvestor from './IndividualInvestor';

import * as redux from 'react-redux';

describe('Individual Investor', () => {


  const useSelectorMock = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
  const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
  beforeEach(() => {
    useSelectorMock.mockClear();
    useDispatchMock.mockClear();
  });

  test('Makes sure it reaches questionaire', async () => {
    useSelectorMock.mockReturnValue({
      offering: {
        payment_enabled: false,
        _id: '61aa480e4e18c1bbfba8f83d',
      },
      payment_enabled: false,
      _id: '61aa480e4e18c1bbfba8f83d',
    });

    const dummyDispatch = jest.fn();
    useDispatchMock.mockReturnValue(dummyDispatch);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *actually run the code* :)  By mocking `useSelector`, you've skipped running all of its actual logic that takes your selector function and runs it when needed.

We would strongly recommend *against* mocking `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. Instead, create an actual Redux store in the test, and wrap the component under test with a `<Provider>`.

You can see examples of how to do this in a reusable `render()` test util in our docs guide on testing:

https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#components

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! How would i got about doing this?  I already wrapped it with a provider is there an example you can provide. Thanks @markerikson

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what markerikson said i managed to actually test the code with this

wrapper for the component with the provider

```
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react';
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// Import your own reducer
import rootReducer from '../redux/reducer/combineReducers';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
function render(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState,
    store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer, preloadedState }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>{children}</Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';
// override render method
export { render };
```

**Then i used that function *render***

```
const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      {
        formBody: {
          offering: {
            data: {
              payment_enabled: false,
              _id: '61aa480e4e18c1bbfba8f83d',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
```

```
const { container } = render( <SomeComponent/>,
     //Pass in store here!
      {
        store: store,
      }
   
    );
```